# Tank collides with walls in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I've been working on this project about tanks (based on game Tank Trouble) and I've made walls appear on the screen. How can I make the tank stop when it collides with the wall.

In the future, I also plan so the bullets can collide with the wall too.

Any help will be appreciated!

Full game code: https://gist.github.com/vairiskovels/1d975e02e4140c116fe259141c75f2e4

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.run = True
        self.screen_width = 1060
        self.screen_height = 798
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bin/sprites/background/background1.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.screen_width, self.screen_height))

        # all_sprites is used to update and draw all sprites together.
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # for collision detection with enemies.
        self.bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # for collision detection with walls.
        self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.tank = Tank()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.tank)

        self.enemy = Enemy()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.enemy)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            bullet = Bullet(self.tank)
            self.bullet_group.add(bullet)
            self.all_sprites.add(bullet)

        # -------------- Walls --------------

        self.wall = Wall(0, 0, 16, 798)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(0, 0, 1060, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(1044, 0, 16, 798)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(0, 782, 1060, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(0, 260, 130, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(260, 0, 16, 130)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(146, 130, 130, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(130, 130, 16, 408)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(146, 522, 130, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(146, 390, 130, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(130, 652, 16, 146)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(146, 652, 130, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(390, 0, 16, 146)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(522, 0, 16, 146)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(390, 130, 148, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(260, 260, 146, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(390, 260, 16, 408)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(406, 390, 132, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(522, 260, 16, 146)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(522, 260, 130, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(522, 522, 16, 260)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(652, 130, 278, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(652, 130, 16, 296)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(782, 0, 16, 146)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(914, 0, 16, 146)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(782, 260, 278, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(782, 390, 148, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(914, 390, 16, 148)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(914, 522, 148, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(914, 652, 148, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(652, 522, 146, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(652, 652, 146, 16)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)

        self.wall = Wall(782, 522, 16, 276)
        self.wall_list.add(self.wall)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.wall)


    def handle_events(self):
        self.tank.handle_events()
        self.enemy.handle_events()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.run = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.run = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = Bullet(self.tank)
                    self.bullet_group.add(bullet)
                    self.all_sprites.add(bullet)

    def update(self):
        # Calls `update` methods of all contained sprites.
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, (0, 0))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)  # Draw the contained sprites.
        pygame.display.update()


class Tank(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bin/sprites/player/player_tank.png")
        self.org_image = self.image.copy()

        # A nicer way to set the start pos with `get_rect`.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(70, 600))

        self.vel = 3

        self.angle = 270  # starts looking right
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0)
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)

        self.hp = 1

    def handle_events(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.angle += 3
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.angle -= 3
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and self.rect.left - 5 > 0 and self.rect.top - 5 > 0 and self.rect.right + 5 < 1060 and self.rect.bottom + 5 < 798:
            self.move(-3)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.rect.left - 5 > 0 and self.rect.top - 5 > 0 and self.rect.right + 5 < 1060 and self.rect.bottom + 5 < 798:
            self.move(3)

        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.org_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def move(self, vel):
        direction = pygame.Vector2(0, vel).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.pos += direction
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bin/sprites/enemy/enemy_tank.png")
        self.org_image = self.image.copy()

        self.spawnx = [600, 850, 860]  # spawning x coord
        self.spawny = [70, 200, 700]  # spawning y coord
        self.i = random.randint(0, len(self.spawnx) - 1)

        # A nicer way to set the start pos with `get_rect`.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.spawnx[self.i], self.spawny[self.i]))

        self.vel = 3
        self.hp = 1

        if self.i == 0:
            self.angle = 180
        elif self.i == 1:
            self.angle = 90
        elif self.i == 2:
            self.angle = 0

        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0)
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)

    def handle_events(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.angle += 3
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.angle -= 3
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.move(-3)
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.move(3)

        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(1, 0).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.org_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def move(self, vel):
        direction = pygame.Vector2(0, vel).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.pos += direction
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])


class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        # Make a wall, of the size specified in the parameters
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(dark_gray)

        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, tank):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bin/sprites/bullet/bullet.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (16, 16))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = tank.rect.centerx + 3  # How much pixels from tank turret on x axis
        self.rect.centery = tank.rect.centery - 25  # How much pixels from tank turret on y axis
        self.angle = tank.angle
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2(0, -10).rotate(-self.angle)
        self.lives = 4  # how many times bounces

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.direction
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.direction.x *= -1
            self.rect.left = 0
            self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
            self.lives -= 1
            if self.lives == 0:
                return self.kill()
            bounce.play()

        if self.rect.right > 1060:
            self.direction.x *= -1
            self.rect.right = 1060
            self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
            self.lives -= 1
            if self.lives == 0:
                return self.kill()
            bounce.play()

        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.direction.y *= -1
            self.rect.top = 0
            self.pos.y = self.rect.centery
            self.lives -= 1
            if self.lives == 0:
                return self.kill()
            bounce.play()

        if self.rect.bottom > 798:
            self.direction.y *= -1
            self.rect.right = 798
            self.pos.y = self.rect.centery
            self.lives -= 1
            if self.lives == 0:
                return self.kill()
            bounce.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tank is a [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object. The walls are [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects, too and collected in the [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) `wall_list`. Thus you can use [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) to detect a collision:

```py
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.tank, self.wall_list, False):
    print("tank collides with wall")
```

Note, [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) returns a list of the `Wall` objects, which caused the collision. In your case the list will probably contain 1 element when the tank collides:

```py
hit_walls = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.tank, self.wall_list, False)
if hit_walls:
    hit_wall = hit_walls[0]
```

Alternatively you can iterate through the walls, which caused the collision:

```py
for hit_wall in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.tank, self.wall_list, False):
    # [...]
```

For instance you can cancel the movement of the tank, when it hits a wall in `Game.handle_events`:

```py
class Game:
    # [...]

    def handle_events(self):

        tank_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.tank.pos)
        self.tank.handle_events()
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.tank, self.wall_list, False): 
            self.tank.pos = tank_pos
            self.tank.rect.center = round(tank_pos[0]), round(tank_pos[1])

        # [...]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to put this in my code but nothing happens when sprites collide

Comment: I put the second and third part of code in Game() under all walls code part

Comment: @kovels I've extended the answer. See the last section, which I've added right now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this one, if it doesn't work this time then I'm dumb

Comment: Interestingly that it works but not the right way. I did what you said me to do but this time tank normal speed is higher than before and when I collide with the wall tank slows down but still goes forward

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it, now it works. Anyway, thank you for the help, appreciate.